# Solving condensate density problem in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, quantum-mechanics, integral-equations

I want to solve for $n_{0}$ for a fixed value of $n$, lets say $n=1$
 $$ n= n_{0}+ \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}dq\left(\dfrac{e_{q}+Un_{0}}{\hbar\omega}-1\right) $$ 
where $e_{q}=2[1-cos(2\pi q)] $ and $\hbar\omega=(e_{q}^{2}+2Un_{0}e_{q})^{1/2} $

Then I want to plot between  $U$ and $n_{0}$. The following is the code in MATLAB.

```
 eq = @(q) 2*(1-cos(2*pi*q));
 hq = @(q,U,n0) ((eq(q))^2+2*U*n0*(eq(q))).^(1/2);
 y = @(q,U,n0) (((eq(q))+(U*n0))/hq(q,U,n0))-1;
 a = -0.5;
 b = 0.5;
 v = @(U,n0) quad(@(q) y(q,U,n0),a,b);
 cv =@(U,n0) n0+(0.5*v)-1;
 n0 = 0.1;
 options = optimset('Display', 'iter'); 
 n = @(U) fsolve(vv,n0,0.1);
 U = 0:0.1:20;
 plot(U,n(U))
```

edit 2 code corrected 
edit 1.

Edit 3

But I still facing the following errors:

Error using  ^ 
Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix.
To compute elementwise POWER, use POWER (.^) instead.

Error in @(q,n0)((eq(q))^2+2*U*n0*(eq(q))).^0.5

Error in @(q,n0)(((eq(q))+(U*n0))/hq(q,n0))-1

Error in @(q)y(q,n0)

Error in quad (line 72)
y = f(x, varargin{:});

Error in @(n0)quad(@(q)y(q,n0),a,b)

Error in @(n0)n0+(0.5*v(n0))-1

Error in simulv1 (line 12)
n = fsolve(cv(n0),n0,0.1,options);

Comment: welcome to StackExchange. It would help if you listed the errors and provided a description of what you have already tried and what it is that you can't seem to work out.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp! As currently posed, your question is unclear. As WolfgangBangerth points out, it's not clear what you've tried. It looks like you're relying on `quad` to calculate the integral, and then passing that integral as a function to `fsolve`. The algorithms used by `fsolve` require derivatives of the nonlinear equation being solved. Since `quad` uses adaptive quadrature algorithms, it would not surprise me if the finite difference derivative approximations used by `fsolve` were ill-behaved. You might have better luck using a non-adaptive quadrature instead.

Comment: Your first step would be fixing the equations in your code as per the answer to [your question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28664254/2278029).

Comment: The first power in your second line needs to be `eq(q).^2`, not `eq(q)^2`. (Before you edit again: the following lines have similar problems; anytime a vector such as `eq(q)` appears, you need `.*`, `./` etc.)